# to_s method is not displaying the right result

Tags: ruby

I have an array: `[1, "2", 3.0, ["a", "b"], "dog"]`

typing `array.to_s` in my command prompt gives me this:

`[1, \"2\", 3.0, [\"a\", \"b\"], \"dog\"]`

Which is wrong, and it is suppose to give me this:

`123.0abdog`

Would someone explain to me why I'm not getting the right result?

Comment: `to_s` used to work like this back in the Ruby 1.8 days but that's long since ceased to be a thing. Now it behaves like `inspect`.

Comment: Apparently, you are reading an outdated tutorial for a long obsolete version of Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

You, probably, want to join array:

```
[1, "2", 3.0, ["a", "b"], "dog"].join
=> "123.0abdog"
```

`to_s` works differently, according to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect), it creates a string representation of an array:

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ].to_s     #=> "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

Comment: OP was asking why they weren't getting the desired result with `to_s`. Maybe explain how `to_s` works differently?

Answer (score 3):

What it's giving you *is* the correct result. `.to_s` only ever returns a string representation of the object you call it on. In this case, it returns what the array looks like when represented as a string. This doesn't just mean flattening and combining all the elements into a string and is not generally intended to mean such.

If you want to run some code to get that result, try:

```
[1, "2", 3.0, ["a", "b"], "dog"].flatten.join
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get rid of the nested array bby using flatten.  Then you can join it into a string.

`[1, "2", 3.0, ["a", "b"], "dog"].flatten.join`